# Listed electric baseboard heaters that permit installation below outlets

Tags: electrical, heating, code-compliance, nec

Are there UL-listed electric baseboard heaters that *do* permit being installed below outlets? The FPN in 210.52:

> Informational Note: Listed baseboard heaters include instructions that may not 
>   permit their installation below receptacle outlets.

uses the word 'may', which makes me wonder if some baseboard heaters can legitimately be installed under a receptacle and others cannot without violating the listing, or if the FPN's wording is not strong enough and could do with revising for the next Code cycle?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, some might be OK... the FPNs are separate from the actual code; they aren't enforceable. However, if the installation instructions prohibit installation below a receptacle, you're going to be considered in violation. I'd be surprised if any of these types of heaters allowed it...

You can always get one of [these.](http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/hvac/heaters/electric-baseboard/baseboard-integral-receptacle-kit-14902-212l-x-212w-x-634h-white?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=Cj0KEQjwhPaqBRDG2uiHzpKLi6ABEiQAk_XXibJqAGuQM-lJujvpVNEYKjXvg6lCamVBumxtrqmxi0oaAv8q8P8HAQ)